# ReactiveJS templates : Iterating Over an Object , using array iteration

Tags: javascript

Im rewriting an angularjs directive ,moving all the markup from angular to reactiveJS, due to the poor dom performance of angularjs.
i have a simple a question about reactiveJS templating.

Template

```
{{#each dataTable:i}}
        <li
            {{#options.keysDisplayName:j}}
                <span>{{dataTable[i][this]}}</span>

            {{/each}}
        </li>
{{/each}}
```

JS

```
    var ractive = new Ractive({
        el: 'details-table',
        template: '#details-table-tmplt',
        data: {
            options:  {
                keysDisplayName : [ 'name', 'age']
            },
            dataTable : [
                {name : 'dog', age:15, gender: 'f'},
                {name : 'cat', age:15, gender: 'f'}
            ]
        }
    });
```

Im printing a table/list , 
I want to iterate on the each row in the dataTable , but only on the keys that present in **options.keysDisplayName** . ( so in this example , gender property  wont be shown)
I guess im missing somthing basic in framework.
Thanks , much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix your template to:

```
{{#each dataTable:i}}
<li>
    {{#each options.keysDisplayName:j}}
       <span>{{dataTable[i][this]}}</span>
    {{/each}}
</li>
{{/each}}
```

After fix the output will be:

```
dog15

cat15
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works either way , (http://jsfiddle.net/fLd86/10/). My problem was i was using the wrong array , keysDisplayName instead of using keys array . Thanks , its a great framework